# reading IR codes from input events

Tags: events

I have an intel nuc7pjyh with a builtin IR receiver and running on ubuntu 20.04 .
Without using lirc and lircd, I want to read IR commands with python.
Using ir-keytable, I have set up some ir-codes->keys.

I'm doing this:

```
import evdev
device = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event12')
for event in device.read_loop():
    print(evdev.categorize(event))
```

"event12" is hardcoded, I got it from ir-keytable. How do I find out that I have to listen at event12 to get the IR codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
device = next(Path("/sys/class/rc/").glob("rc*/input*/event*/"),None)
if device == None:
    devpath = None
else:
    devpath = f"/dev/input/{device.name}"
```